# Logical AND aggregation in SSRS, RDLC

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I created a new RDLC report using Report Wizard, that generated a tablix for me. The tablix uses one of the DataSet properties to group items by rows. After each group there is a subtotal displayed for each integer column by following expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!SourceCount.Value)
```

I would like to do a similar "subtotal" but for boolean columns - it should return the logical AND for the set of values in a given group

Comment: It helps if you tell us what you've tried, include an example dataset, and if you're specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: I need to have an aggregation on a set of booleans that returns the logical AND. Similar to the built-in SUM function for integers e.g. =And(Fields!SourceCount.Value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression works for me:

```
=IIf(Sum(IIf(Not(Fields!val.Value), 1, 0)) Mod 2 <> 0
  , false
  , true)
```

This counts the number of *FALSE* values; if the number is even the `AND` of the set must be *TRUE*, else *FALSE*.

I put the following together to test.

DataSet:

[image]

Report in Designer:

[image]

The **Logical AND** expression is the same as the one described above. End result:

[image]

**Edit after comment:**

If all you're looking for is the existence of one or more *FALSE* values in the data scope, you can change the expression to the following:

```
=IIf(Sum(IIf(Not(Fields!val.Value), 1, 0)) > 0
  , false
  , true)
```

So if there is at least one *FALSE* value, return *FALSE* for the aggregation.

Updated report:

[image]

Maybe this is what you're after?

Comment: So I tried to use your expression like this
=IIf(Sum(IIf(Not(Fields!SourceCount.Value), 1, 0)) Mod 2 <> 0, false, true) 
but it doesn't work for me. I have 3 different sets with all values being TRUE and it returns False for 2 of them and True for one set.

Comment: You can see it works for me - why don't you amend your question with the full details of a DataSet with a few rows where this isn't working so there is a readily testable case? Can you confirm `SourceCount` is actually a *boolean* column? The name would suggest otherwise.

Comment: sorry, you were right about me using a wrong field. However, I think your solution is still wrong, as "False AND False" should give FALSE. Basically if there is a single FALSE the entire result should be FALSE

Comment: I've amended the expression slightly to return *FALSE* if there are any *FALSE* rows in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old and already answered question, but recently I had similar needing, and I found that `Max` and `Min` aggregate functions work fine with `Boolean`, so we can directly use them as aggregate logical OR and AND:

```
=Max(Fields!val.Value) 'Boolean OR (True if at least one value is True)
=Min(Fields!val.Value) 'Boolean AND (True only if all values are True)
```